# Test a webpage without having downloaded its resources yet

Tags: caching, testing, browser, refresh, html

Each time I want to test a webpage that I modified, let's say I added or changed the source of an image, the browser loads that image from that page for the first time, and then when I keep refreshing it, the image just holds still like I've been there before (it doesn't start to download it again).

So (as a debug mode for the developer), I want the browser to download all the related resources over again so I don't have to clean the cache and everything from my browser each time I want to test each single thing I add or modify, for instance a different image.

How am I supposed to do that? Is there a name for that?

I thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit Ctrl+F5 to reload, it should clear the cache. Note however that images loaded dynamically by a script may not be cleared from cache, but in this case you can add `?x="+new Date().getTime()` to bust the cache for testing.

Comment: I don't know what you're referring with the `?x="` part of the code, sorry I'm still a noob at this. :)

Answer (score 0):

on a MAC:
Command+Shift+R

[Firefox shortcuts link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly)